# --max-semi-space-size vs --max-old-space-size

Tags: node.js, v8

What is the the difference between

[--max-old-space-size](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--max-old-space-sizesize-in-megabytes) vs [--max-semi-space-size](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--max-old-space-sizesize-in-megabytes) in the Nodejs docs?

I understand that they are related to V8 garbage collector, but there doesn't seem to be any clear explanation within the docs.

Answer (score 0):

> Garbage collection is the process of reclaiming the memory occupied by
> objects that are no longer in use by the application. Usually, memory
> allocation is cheap while it’s expensive to collect when the memory
> pool is exhausted.
>
> An object is a candidate for garbage collection when it is unreachable
> from the root node, so not referenced by the root object or any other
> active objects. Root objects can be global objects, DOM elements or
> local variables.
>
> The heap has two main segments, the **New Space** and the **Old
> Space**. The **New Space** is where new allocations are happening; it
> is fast to collect garbage here and has a size of ~1-8MBs. Objects
> living in the New Space are called Young Generation. The **Old Space**
> where the objects that survived the collector in the New Space are
> promoted into – they are called the Old Generation. Allocation in the
> Old Space is fast, however collection is expensive so it is
> infrequently performed .

---

**--max-old-space-size** is related to the **Old Space** limit whereas **max-semi-space-size** is related to the **New Space**.

**New Space** has a smaller buffer (as the GC runs more frequently) whereas **Old Space** is larger and runs less often.

---

[source: risingstack garbage collection](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-node-js-garbage-collection/).

[source: hunting a ghost](https://blog.risingstack.com/finding-a-memory-leak-in-node-js/)